# Recreate shape as in xml file by using code and set width programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I already have shape code and now I need to draw the same programmatically and set its width according to the length of texts in an array. I am not able to reproduce the same using path data.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="2778"
    android:viewportHeight="1250"
    android:width="250.0002dp"
    android:height="112.5dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M2764 1250L0 1250 0 0l2256 0 4 4 513 468 4 4 0 774 -14 0 0 0zm-2737 -27l2723 0 0 -736L2245 26 27 26 27 1222Z"
        android:fillColor="#FF6E00" />
</vector>
```

[Output shape should be this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS8bY.png)

Please help me on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** By Creating custom shape:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape;

public class RectangleCutCorner extends Shape {
    private int backgroundColor  = Color.BLACK;
    private float strokeWidth = 1.0f;
    private static final float CORNER = 35.0f;

    private final Paint border = new Paint();
    private final Path  path;

    public RectangleCutCorner() {
        path = new Path();
        border.setColor(backgroundColor);
        border.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        border.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        border.setAntiAlias(true);
        border.setDither(true);
        border.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        border.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    //for setting stroke width programmatically
    public void setStrokeWidthToLayout(float strokeWidth){
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        border.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }

    //for setting background/stroke color programmatically
    public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor){
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        border.setColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    //for setting background filled or not programmatically
    public void setBackgroundFill(boolean isFilled){
      if(isFilled){
          border.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      }else{
          border.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResize(float width, float height) {
        super.onResize(width, height);

        float dx = strokeWidth/2.0f;
        float dy = strokeWidth/2.0f;
        float x  = dx;
        float y  = dy;
        float w  = width  - dx;
        float h  = height - dy;
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x + CORNER,y);
        path.lineTo(w - CORNER,y);
        path.lineTo(w,y + CORNER);
        path.lineTo(w, h);
        path.lineTo(x + CORNER,h);
        path.lineTo(dx,h);
        path.lineTo(dx,y);
        path.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        canvas.drawPath(path,border);
    }
}
```

***How to use this programmatically:***

```
    RectangleCutCorner rectangleCutCorner = new RectangleCutCorner();
    // set color
    rectangleCutCorner.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
    //set fill background (true/false)
    rectangleCutCorner.setBackgroundFill(false);
    // set stroke width
    rectangleCutCorner.setStrokeWidthToLayout(2.5f);
    // set background to view
    view.setBackground(new ShapeDrawable(rectangleCutCorner));
```

Output for above code is:

[image]

**Method 2:** By Using Material Shape Drawable:

Add this dependency into build.gradle(app) file:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`

***How to use:***

```
    ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, 20)
            .build();
    MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled},
    };
    int[] colors = new int[] {
            Color.WHITE,
    };
    ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    // set background to drawable
    shapeDrawable.setFillColor(myList);
    // set stroke and to view
    shapeDrawable.setStroke(1.5f, Color.BLACK);
    // set background to view
    ViewCompat.setBackground(tvUrl, shapeDrawable);
```

Output for above code is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Android Geek the solution was perfect.. is it possible to add width and height to this shape while creating? Because i need to calculate the length of the text and measure it in dp and assign width and height to shape in dp..

Comment: i need 15 reputation i guess to mark answer as correct.. @Android Geek Thanks a lot!

Comment: the first one is working great.. when i tried the second solution, it works fine in Android 10, then i tried the same in Android Marshmallow, the color was different.. For both transparent and light brown color(#FF6E00), the background was only black.. so i am going with first solution.. Thanks again @android-geek